# Using an epigraph at the title page of a JHEP article

Tags: article, epigraphs

I am trying to include a dedication on the title page of an article. To do so, I am using the `epigraph` environment and command. The problem that I have is that I would like to have the epigraph right after the abstract at the right-bottom of the page.

I tried putting the `epigraph` command after the abstract but it goes at the top of the page. Any suggestions?

The code is given below

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{jheppub}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\graphicspath{{Figs/}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref, pdfsync, epstopdf, enumerate}
\usepackage{epigraph}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hypersetup{colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,
citecolor={Red},
linkcolor={Red},pdfstartview=FitH,
urlcolor={Red}}
\def\myurl#1#2{\href{http://#1}{#2}}
\def\hhref#1{\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{arXiv:#1}} % in bibliography
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{My project}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author[a]{author a,}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\affiliation[a]{some affiliation}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\emailAdd{random@something.com}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\abstract{this is the abstract placeholder}
\epigraph{my dedication}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                                                          
\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{footnote}{0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliography{lit}{}
\bibliographystyle{utphys}

\end{document}
```

I also tried to include the command after the `maketitle` command but then the code simply places the `epigraph` after the contents.

Comment: Add a blank line between the abstract and the \epigraph command.

Comment: @Bernard if I use the command \newline it gives an error that there is no line there. And if I use \hfill \break nothing happens

Comment: I didn't say to use thiscommand, I advised to add a blank line in the code. That is because the `\epigraph` command has to be written between paragraphs (in vertical mode).

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks for the explanation, however I left a completely blank line between the abstract and the epigraph and the dedication still appears on the top of the page.

Comment: Strange…And if instead, you just add the `\par` command right after `\end{abstract}`?

Comment: @Bernard unfortunately this also does not work. But thanks for your time and suggestions anyway

Comment: Did you check whether just the code you posted and the blank line (or the `\par`) added works? I suspect there's something else in your real code you didn't post, which inhibits the placement of the epigraph as you'd like.

Comment: @Bernard I tried all your suggestions with the code posted here and this is why there is not a part of my code that is not posted and interferes. Did you try your suggestions with the given code and it worked?

Comment: I did try them, just commenting some packages that are not installed on my system and seem unrelated to this kind of problem.

Comment: @Bernard Could you please tell me which ones so I can give that a go and build from there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115236/discussion-between-bernard-and-disp0sable-h3r0).

Comment: I don't know where the `jheppub` package comes from so I ignored it in processing your MWE. The epigraph appears below the abstract if there is an empty line between the abstact and epigraph code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some very useful comments and some discussion with @Bernard I found a resolution.

There exists a macro built-in the JHEP template that can be used.

It is `\dedicated{...}` and places the dedication right beneath the abstract on the titlepage.